# Identifying similar data in a multiple pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, selection

I would like to work on value from a pandas dataframe that are identified to be the same based on two columns in a dataframe. I could not find an efficient way for this purpose. Please see the following explanation of the code.

The dataframe df below shows branch information that are connected between the first node in a and the second node in b.

The first two rows of df shows branch that are connected with: (Nod1, Nod2) and (Node2, Nod1). These two are regarded the same branches, and I want to add the value in c for both of them: 0.15+0.152.

I thought that I can do this by making a pairing of these two by using zip and work with these pairs (doesn't matter the sequence of node). However I could not come to a good way for this purpose without a loop.

is there anyway to achieve my purpose? e.g., checking only the entry 'uniq' column but disregarding the sequence of node in it to acquire the value c.

```
a = ['Nod1', 'Nod2', 'Node3', 'Node1']
b = ['Nod2', 'Nod1', 'Node4', 'Node5']
c = [0.15, 0.152, 0.23, 0.24]

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': a, 'b':b, 'c':c})
print(df)

       a      b      c
0   Nod1   Nod2  0.150
1   Nod2   Nod1  0.152
2  Node3  Node4  0.230
3  Node1  Node5  0.240
#-------------------------------------------------------------
d = [j for j in zip(a, b)]
df['uniq'] = d
print (df)
       a      b      c            uniq
0   Nod1   Nod2  0.150    (Nod1, Nod2)
1   Nod2   Nod1  0.152    (Nod2, Nod1)
2  Node3  Node4  0.230  (Node3, Node4)
3  Node1  Node5  0.240  (Node1, Node5)
```

Comment: Is not clear what output do you want? The sum of `0.15 + 0.152`?

Comment: yes, in the end I want to sum the value in c, ie 0.15+0.152 = 0.32

Comment: WHat happens if there is a `node3 node1`, and a `node1 node3`, i.e a third connected node?

Comment: (node3, node1) = (node1, node3). however, these are not the same as (node1, node2) or (nod2, nod1)

Comment: So you want another sum for `node3, node1` or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
# get 'a' and 'b' into a state where we can group them
df['ab'] = df.apply(lambda _: str(sorted([_['a'], _['b']])), axis=1)

# groupby this new column and sum on c
df.groupby('ab')['c'].sum()
```

Output:

```
ab
['Nod1', 'Nod2']      0.302
['Node1', 'Node5']    0.240
['Node3', 'Node4']    0.230
Name: c, dtype: float64
```